# Pattern Matching : function to return number of additions and constants

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am learning pattern matching in Haskell and I found some exercises which are said to be good for pattern matching.

Is there anyone who can give a little information about how to write a function that will return the number of addition operations in an expression?

I looked a little bit but couldn't find any information about it. Actually how can I return the number of operations in Haskell?

Another exercise which I don't understand is writing a function that will return the number of constants in an expression. I didn't understand what they meant with number of constants. Used variables in the expression maybe?

EDIT:

I forgot to add the definition of expressions. What I found related to this is:

**Example (expression tree)**

```
data Expression = Constant Integer
        | Negate Expression
        | Add Expression Expression
        | Multiply Expression Expression
   deriving Show
```

**Example (evaluate an expression)**

```
eval e = case e of
    Constant c -> c
    Negate e    -> -(eval e)
    Add e1 e2     -> (eval e1) + (eval e2)
    Multiply e1 e2 -> (eval e1) * (eval e2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: In what form are the expressions? Could you link to the exercises?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add. Edited but still couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Counting additions

Let's look at when there's an addition:

```
data Expression = Constant Integer
                | Negate Expression
                | Add Expression Expression  -- here!
                | Multiply Expression Expression
```

OK, let's make a patternmatching function for that

```
countAdds :: Expression -> Int
```

None in a constant:

```
countAdds (Constant i) = 0
```

If you negated something, there might have been adds in that - let's just count them and return that as the answer:

```
countAdds (Negate expr) = countAdds expr -- cool recursion trick
```

If there's an `Add` here, that's one, but there might be more adds in the two expressions you're adding:

```
countAdds (Add expr1 expr2) = 1 + countAdds expr1 + countAdds expr2
```

but in a `Multiply`, you just have however many are in the two expressions you're multiplying:

```
countAdds (Multiply expr1 expr2) = countAdds expr1 + countAdds expr2
```

All together that gives:

```
countAdds :: Expression -> Int
countAdds (Constant i) = 0
countAdds (Negate expr) = countAdds expr -- cool recursion trick
countAdds (Add expr1 expr2) = 1 + countAdds expr1 + countAdds expr2
countAdds (Multiply expr1 expr2) = countAdds expr1 + countAdds expr2
```

### Counting other things

You can solve the other problems a similar way to the way I counted additions.

For the total number of operations, you'll need to have `1 +` for the `Multiply` pattern, and possibly for the `Negate` one as well. (I don't know whether you just wanted to count binary operations like addition and multiplication or also unary operations like negation.)

Counting the constants works in a very similar way, except that you'd use `1` where I used `0`. Would you need any `1 +`?

Have a go and see how you get on.